# Is a magnetic compass required for an IFR flight?

Tags: faa-regulations

Is a stand-alone magnetic compass required for an IFR fight when the aircraft has a glass panel with a [Horizontal Situation Indicator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horizontal_situation_indicator)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is a magnetic compass required for VFR?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/7995/is-a-magnetic-compass-required-for-vfr)

Comment: @rbp Um, not to be rude but...  Unless IFR and VFR became the same thing, these are not the same question.

Comment: @Jay rbp is correct, the answer to the other question anwers this question though, as the text further down states that all items required for VFR flights are also required for IFR flights.

Comment: @SentryRaven Ah, fair enough.  I guess I'm more looking at it from a "search" perspective.  People looking for an answer to an IFR question aren't likely to look at a VFR question, that's all I'm saying.

Comment: I think it's worthwhile leaving this as a standalone question: Although the other includes mention of IFR flight as part of the context of the answer, it is still a better fit for the SE Q&A format to keep this as a separate question, unless we also modify the Question of the other post to better fit a generic IFR/VFR answer.

Answer (score 7):

A magnetic heading indicator is required, but not necessarily a wet compass, like this one:

[image: Magnetic Compass / Panel mounted]
<sup>Image Source: [Wikipedia - Author: Chopper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Aero_Magnetic_Compass.jpg)</sup>

Digital devices or combined devices are also possible:

[image: HSI]
<sup>Image Source: [WikiPedia - Author: Mysid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Horizontal_situation_indicator-en.svg)</sup>

The required equipment for **VFR** flights states, as already posted in [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/7995/is-a-magnetic-compass-required-for-vfr):

> §[91.205](http://rgl.faa.gov/Regulatory_and_Guidance_Library/rgFar.nsf/FARSBySectLookup/91.205)   Powered civil aircraft with standard category U.S. airworthiness certificates: Instrument and equipment requirements.
>
> (a) General. Except as provided in paragraphs (c)(3) and (e) of this section, no person may operate a powered civil aircraft with a standard category U.S. airworthiness certificate in any operation described in paragraphs (b) through (f) of this section unless that aircraft contains the instruments and equipment specified in those paragraphs (or FAA-approved equivalents) for that type of operation, and those instruments and items of equipment are in operable condition.
>
> (b) Visual-flight rules (day). For VFR flight during the day, the following instruments and equipment are required:
>
> ...
>
> **(3) Magnetic direction indicator.**
>
> ...

The text further states for **IFR**:

> (d) Instrument flight rules. For IFR flight, the following instruments and equipment are required:
>
> **(1) Instruments and equipment specified in paragraph (b) of this section, and, for night flight, instruments and equipment specified in paragraph (c) of this section.**
>
> ...

Comment: Note that as [@rbp points out](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/11631) the magnetic direction indicator is not required to be a separate piece of hardware (such as a wet compass). My understanding is that for glass panels it's usually integrated into the HSI by slaving that to a magnetometer (which has the benefit of eliminating the need to correct the DG/HSI for gyroscopic precession as well).

Comment: @voretaq7 I edited my answer to incorporate that.

Comment: The device depicted is not a _magnetic_ direction indicator. It is a HSI containing a _heading_ indictor which works on gyroscopes.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie, but it has no correction knob, so it must be slaved to a magnetic device. A heading indicator would be this:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:C172_heading_indicator.jpg

Comment: @SentryRaven, how would the deviation be set? (Difference between magnetic and true North.) The pilot will want the true North heading to be displayed on the device in front of him.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie You mean the variation? Deviation is usually read on magnetic compasses via a deviation table next to the compass. I am not aware of variation ever being entered into HSI or Compasses, you factor it in during flight-planning.

Comment: @SentryRaven, when you set the heading indicator to the compass, you must then still correct for the variation (indeed, "variation", not "deviation" - getting sloppy on my terminology) so the heading indicator points to true North, not magnetic. This difference can be very significant (when flying to Grand Canyon it was 15 degrees or so!). You also have to regularly adjust the heading indicator as the gyroscopes keep it in its originally set position while true North "moves" as you airplane "moves". The HSI is to my knowledge a heading indicator, not a compass. (I am a C172 pilot.)

Comment: This must be a difference in training, I never set my gyro to true north, but slave it to the readout on my wet compass. Variation is only compensated during flight-planning, not on the device itself via adjusting. In the case of the above HSI, there is no adjustment knob to correct for variation or to re-adjust due to gyro-drift, it must be slaved to a magnetic device, as the heading select and course select knobs are for different things.

Comment: @SentryRaven, you are right. I haven't flown in a couple of years. Must have lost a lot. The heading indicator is set to the compass; variance is applied to the course on the map (which is drawn in true North) during flight planning, on the ground, and in the cockpit when you have to ammend your plan.

Answer (score 4):

If you mean a "whiskey compass," like the thing that sits above the center of the panel, then the answer is **no**.

[image]

For aircraft certified under Part 23, as described in [AC 23.1311-1C](http://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Advisory_Circular/AC%2023.1311-1C.pdf):

> Section 23.1303(c), Amendment 23-62, amended the requirement from “A
>   direction indicator (non-stabilized magnetic compass)” to “A magnetic
>   direction indicator.” As new technology becomes more affordable for
>   part 23 airplanes, many **electronic flight instrument systems will use
>   magnetically stabilized direction indicators** (or electric compass
>   systems) to measure and indicate the airplane heading to provide
>   better performance.

A [fluxgate compass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluxgate_compass), which can be remotely mounted in the wing or the tail would also satisfy the regs.

Also, [MEMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microelectromechanical_systems) fluxgates are being developed right now, which could be integrated directly into an [AHRS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attitude_and_heading_reference_system). And there are [a number of other technologies](http://www.sensorsmag.com/sensors/electric-magnetic/a-new-perspective-magnetic-field-sensing-855) being developed to sense the earth's magnetic field.

Comment: I do wonder though, what do they do in case of an electrical failure? No mechanical backup required?

Comment: This still effectively requires a magnetic compass ("magnetic direction indicator") - a device which uses magnetism to determine your current heading, it just doesn't have to be a traditional wet compass. You could not, for example, legally fly a glass panel aircraft which only had GPS and MEMS or laser gyros in order to determine and display heading.

Comment: @voretaq7 but you could with a solid-state fluxgate compass

Comment: Yes - a fluxgate (or other electric magnetometer) is still a "magnetic direction indicator" :)

Comment: Does the definition "magnetic direction indicator" allow the pick-up device to be separated from the display device? Or is one of the aspects of the requirement that, when everything else fails, there is still a reliable (magnetic) heading indicator available in the cockpit?

Comment: It's actually better to have the sensor on the wing or in the tail to reduce electro-magnetic interference.